# Object Not Found! Opening Images From a Folder

Tags: php, html, fopen

So I have an image in the folder that I want to open with the file name of "newfile.jpg" from the folder of "/files". What is the best way of opening the image?

I have tried:

```
<?php
    $dir = "/files/";
    $open = fopen($dir."newfile.jpg", "r");

    echo "<a target='_blank' href='".$open."'>";
    echo "Open File";
    echo "</a>"
?>
```

It gave me an "Object Not Found!" error

Comment: Object not found is like a 404 not found error the file is not exist in  your file directory

Comment: @Jerson but it still displays that error if I put it in the same folder with the file

Comment: @eagle.exe When referring to a file in the same folder, $dir should be `"./"`

Comment: @Laif I tried it with the file being in "/files/", and with the same folder using "./newfile.jpg/", but result is still "object not found".

Comment: @eagle.exe Please screenshot or fully represent your file hierarchy so we can tell where everything is in reality

Comment: @Laif the full file hierachy is C:\xampp\htdocs\files\newfile.jpg and the php file is in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: @eagle.exe try `./files/newfile.jpg`

Comment: [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a resource, simply placing it in a string wont work.

Comment: @Laif I'm sorry but it is still not working

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If I echo it, it gives Resource id #3 what should I do with it?

Comment: You shouldn’t do _anything_ with it, because reading the file _content_ makes little sense at this point to begin with. If you want to _link to_ a file, then specify the file _name_ (and necessary folder path, if any), in the `href` attribute of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer:

```
echo"<a target='_blank' href='".$dir."newfile.jpg"."'>"
```